# Instantiating an array of inaccessible class through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am currently helping in the development of a game using Unity3D engine. We need to use a `Curve Editor` for describing scale of the damage of a given spell. There is already a Curve Editor class with the desired functionality in the C# assembly of Unity3D engine, but it is inaccessible. I tried to instantiate an object of that type via Reflection. However I encountered a problem. The constructor of this class requires a few arguments 1 of which happens to be an array of another inaccessible class. And here is the problem. I am able to construct an object via reflection but not an array of objects of that type. Here is the constructor:

```
public CurveEditor(Rect rect, CurveWrapper[] curves, bool minimalGUI){...}
```

I am able to construct a `CurveWrapper` object with `Reflection`, but not a whole array. I tried to create `Object[]` array and put a few `CurveWrapper` objects inside but when I pass this array to the constructor through reflection I get invalid argument exception.

Can anybody assist me on this one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for [`Array.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.createinstance.aspx).

```
Type type = ...; // However you get to CurveWrapper
IList array = Array.CreateInstance(type, 2);
array[0] = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
array[1] = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

I have to say though, if `CurveEditor` is inaccessible, I *wouldn't* try to get at it very reflection. Even if it works now, I would view it as entirely reasonable for the Unity3D folks to make incompatible changes to it later. Messing with non-public APIs leads to very brittle code.

Comment: I know it is not a good idea. We need something simple and we need it fast. No time to develop new CurveEditor. Plus it is temporary.

Comment: @DimitarKrastev: If you say so. I'd advise you to actively try to delete the code as fast as possible though. I've heard those exact excuses for code which has stayed in code-bases for far too long and cuased lots of problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing an editor for something in Unity3D then most, if not all, of what you will need is part of the `EditorGUI` helper, like [`EditorGUI.CurveField`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.CurveField.html) which will render a curve editor in the inspector for you (provided you're working in a editor class for the right type of object).

There should be no need to instantiate one manually.